# Listener doctrine.event_listener:onFlush, security.token_storage always null

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, listener, symfony

i'm trying to get the currently logged in user in a Listener written by me (worked in symfony2, but not in Symfony 3.2.2 anymore).

My problem is that the security.token_storage->getToken() is always null.

What i found was the hint that the securityListener might not be executed by this point; so i get no token -> therefore no user.

So this is the service declaration (service.xml)

```
acme.history_logging_listener:
  class: Acme\EventListener\HistoryLoggingListener
    arguments:
      - "@service_container"
      - "@security.token_storage"
    tags:
      - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }
```

and here is the Classcode

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $oContainer, TokenStorageInterface $oTokenStorage)
{
    $this->_oTokenStorage = $oTokenStorage;
}

public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    \dump($this->_oTokenStorage->getToken()); // should contain a value (not null)
    die();
}
```

## EDIT

Token will be filled after second call of the listener; first iteration do not have data; so it is okay for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set it as a private variable in another event, such as `prePersist` and/or `preUpdate` and then access `onFlush`?

Members set in the listener in this way should persist for the duration of any request.

Comment: thx for the hint! i tried it and checked for the token, no success; but on the second call of the listener (somehow later) the token was filled :) i think the solution was to not use die() and check for later iterations :]. Data, to this time, were not existing so the token is available at the second time and serve my needs. THX!